# How to set Rx Queue = N in linux / in Qemu / KVM?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, kvm, qemu

I have configured 8 multiple queues on my CentOS VM box (running on KVM).

```
<interface type='direct' trustGuestRxFilters='yes'>
  <source dev='ens113f0' mode='passthrough'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <driver name='vhost' queues='8'/>
</interface>
```

I can find 8 queues are created on VM using ethtool.

```
[centos@vm ~]$ ethtool -l eth1
Channel parameters for eth1:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:     0
TX:     0
Other:      0
Combined:   8
Current hardware settings:
RX:     0
TX:     0
Other:      0
Combined:   4
```

Now, I wanted to restrict 1 RX queue and 2 TX queues for my DPDK application. I am trying to set the same using ethtool but it is throwing below error:

```
[centos@vm ~]$ sudo ethtool -L eth1 rx 1 tx 2
Cannot set device channel parameters: Invalid argument
```

I can set combined queues = 2 but not specific RX / TX queues.

```
[centos@vm ~]$ sudo ethtool -L eth1 combined 2
[centos@vm ~]$ ethtool -l eth1
Channel parameters for eth1:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:     0
TX:     0
Other:      0
Combined:   8
Current hardware settings:
RX:     0
TX:     0
Other:      0
Combined:   2
```

Any reason / justification of it??

Is there any other way I can set RX queues and TX queues in linux?

Is there any way I can specify RX & TX queues size in libvirt XML / Qemu command? I googled it before posting this question but couldn't find anything. I wanted to specify 1 RX queue & 2 TX queues.

Thank you.